# C++ library to compress files with password protection

Tags: library, c++, archiving, file-compression, zip

I would like to ask for any recommendation for good C++ library to compress files/folders (usually the libs are stream oriented without good file support).

Currently we use minizip (based on zlib) but it is not very up to date and password protection is weak. Is something better available?

What we need:
- multiplatform (Windows and Linux)
- good password protection
- some common archive type so people can extract it without problems (7z, zip, rar and things like that)
- free for commercial use would be good
- both compress and extract availability

I have not found something very good yet. As I have said, zip encryption is not very good. I have found libarchive which I thought I could use for 7z, but it is read-only for that format. Do you have any experience with libraries like that?

Thanks for help!